# MySQL: Cannot add foreign key constraint Error

Tags: mysql, sql

The first table is LocationTime table and the second table is Student table.
I am adding a Foreign Key using 'ALTER'. But I got the error below. Why am I getting the error?

> Cannot add foreign key constraint Error

```
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| CourseN | varchar(3)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Quarter | varchar(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| DayTime | varchar(7)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| RoomN   | varchar(3)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| studentName | varchar(15) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| CourseN     | varchar(3)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Quarter     | varchar(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+


ALTER TABLE Student  
ADD FOREIGN KEY (Quarter) REFERENCES LocationTime (Quarter) 
ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the fact that `Quarter` is a member of a *composite key* (`CouresN`, `Quarter` and `DayTime` forms the primary key for the `LocationTime` table). It is not possible to declare a Foreign Key Constraint on another table that is associated only with the `Quarter`, it should also include the other parts of the composite key. One possible solution to your problem it would be to declare other columns as your primary keys. Furthermore, I don't see the reason why you don't use a column with a auto generated INT (IDENTITY) as you primary key, or a column with an auto generated GUID.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to `INSERT a value` into the table `table_1` that does not exist in the table `table_2` then you will get the error.

Since you have a Foreign Key on the `table_1` field, you have to have the `same value` in the `table_2`.

> See a [non-working demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5acfc/1). This demo shows that the value for Codigo does not exist in the Fabricantes table so it throws the error message. Here is a [working demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/15171/1) which shows that the value is in the table first.